# CSS & Javascript Effect: arraning characters justified with different spacing between letters. Mousemove influenced

Tags: javascript, html, css, experimental-design

I have a two words "Word" and "Arrangement" with various spacing inbetween those characters.

[image]

```
<h1 id="logo">
    <span class="word">
        <span class="w">w</span>
        <span class="o">o</span>
        <span class="r">r</span>
        <span class="d">d</span>
    </span>
    <span class="arrangement">
        <span class="a1">a</span>
        <span class="r1">r</span>
        <span class="r2">r</span>
        <span class="a2">a</span>
        <span class="n1">n</span>
        <span class="g">g</span>
        <span class="e1">e</span>
        <span class="m">m</span>
        <span class="e2">e</span>
        <span class="n2">n</span>
        <span class="t">t</span>
    </span>
</h1>
```

I want the spacing between the characters to move slightly when I move my mouse along the screen. For example, when I move to the right, the spacing on the left should increase and get tighter on the right. Vice versa.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/K9AU7/)

**What is the best way to do this?**

---

*I have no idea if I'm even on the right path of doing this. 
It would be even cooler if the spacing is random on every page load. 
There is just one rule. The two words should still be distinguishable. 
Like in the sample above you can clearly read "word arrangement".*

Kind Regards,
Sepp88

Comment: I will give you idea.. when user hovers on first element, run a loop from next sibling element.. slowly increasing the gap. if the user hovers on last element then do the looping from previous sibling element.

Comment: Can you give me an example on my jsfiddle?

Comment: sorry no time.. I will try if possible.

Comment: I wrote some code just to give you an idea.. [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/s7QSC/). I am not saying it is the ideal way though. it is just my point of view.

Comment: Thank you, however is this even the best way of doing this? Any other solutions? Maybe inserting `&nbsp;` between the letters in order to do that?

Comment: yeah sounds good. :). try giving this post bounty. you might get a solution which you are looking for.

Comment: To get a smooth look you should use jQuerys `animate` as well.

Comment: Hello @matt, do you need the HTML structure to be kept as is? Or are you open to any creative input?

Comment: I'm open to everything.

Comment: There is a exemple of what you can do http://jsfiddle.net/FZAGD/ This is not very smooth and the behavior is strange sometimes but it can maybe give you some ideas.

Answer (score 12):

You could use JavaScript to detect the mosue cursor and add different margin to every word.
I write this example, you could try it.

http://jsfiddle.net/emn178/K9AU7/3/

```
<script>
var maxSpacing = 20;
var screenWidth;

function mousemove(e)
{
    var x = e.pageX;
    var elements = $('.words').children();
    var part = screenWidth / elements.length;
    elements.each(function(i) {
        var margin = Math.abs((part * i - x) / screenWidth * maxSpacing) / 2;
        $(this).css('margin-left', margin);
        $(this).css('margin-right', margin);
    });
}

function resize()
{
    screenWidth = $(document).width();
}

$(window).on('mousemove', mousemove);
$(window).on('resize', resize);

$(document).ready(function() {
    resize();
});
</script>

<h1 id="logo">
    <span class="words">
        <span>w</span>
        <span>o</span>
        <span>r</span>
        <span>d</span>
        <span>a</span>
        <span>r</span>
        <span>r</span>
        <span>a</span>
        <span>n</span>
        <span>g</span>
        <span>e</span>
        <span>m</span>
        <span>e</span>
        <span>n</span>
        <span>t</span>
    </span>
</h1>
```

Edit:
I did a little change let it looks better.

http://jsfiddle.net/emn178/K9AU7/7/

Comment: is this also possible so that it never breaks into a second line?

Comment: sure, add `white-space: nowrap;` to h1

Comment: this would be the perfect solution if (when adding `white-space:nowrap;` the type wouldn't overflow the page. The two words should always stay inside the current page width.

Answer (score 6):

I have achieved your scenario in the below Fiddle.

> [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eScD7/)

Please check in the above link.. and it might helps you otherwise definitely it will give any idea to your requirement..

And also here I have created the words and characters dynamically. So you can enter any words or line in the input box and can generate the moving letters by clicking the button.

Here is the logic i have used

**Script:**

```
function _mouseEnter(e) {
    var _span = $(this).children(".char");
    var len = _span.length, count = 1;

    _span.eq(0).addClass("padd");
    clearInterval(timer);

    timer = setInterval(function () {
        _span.removeClass("padd");
        _span.eq(count).addClass("padd");
        count++;
        if (count == len) count = 0;
    }, 500);
}

function _mouseLeave(e) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    $(this).children("span").removeClass("padd");
}
```

**CSS:**

```
    .word
    {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-right: 30px;
    }
    .word .char
    {
        color: red;
        position: relative;
        -moz-transition: all .5s linear;
        -webkit-transition: all .5s linear;
        -o-transition: all .5s linear;
        transition: all .5s linear;
    }
    .word .char.padd
    {
        color: blue;
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I had tried to use binomial distribution to do this. 
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ohmycode/L7e2U/1/)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1#logo {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size:1.8em;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}

h1#logo span { display: inline-block }
h1#logo span:first-child { margin-left: 0 !important }
h1#logo span:last-child { margin-right: 0 !important }

</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        var $spans = $('#logo span');
        var $h1 = $('#logo');
        var h1pos = $h1.offset();
        var h1Width = $h1.width();
        var contentWidth = 0;   

        $spans.each(function(){ contentWidth += $(this).width() });

        var margin = ( h1Width - contentWidth ) / ( $spans.length - 1 ) / 2 ;

        var count = $spans.length - 1;
        var n = count * 2 - 1;
        var min = 5;
        var l = h1Width - contentWidth - min * ( n + 1 );

        function mousemove(e){
            var x = e.pageX;
            if ( typeof x === 'undefined' || x < h1pos.left || x > h1pos.left + h1Width ){
                $spans.each(function(){
                    $(this).css('margin-right', margin);
                    $(this).css('margin-left', margin);
                });
            } else {
                var p = x / h1Width;

                $spans.each(function(i){
                    if( i == 0 ){
                        $(this).css('margin-right', pmf( n, i, p ) * l + min );
                        $(this).css('margin-left', 0);
                    } else if ( i < count ) {
                        $(this).css('margin-right', pmf( n, 2 * i, p ) * l + min );
                        $(this).css('margin-left', pmf( n, 2 * i - 1, p ) * l + min );
                    } else {
                        $(this).css('margin-right', 0);
                        $(this).css('margin-left', pmf( n, 2 * i - 1, p ) * l + min );
                    }
                });
            }       
        }

        $(window).on('mousemove', mousemove);
        $(window).trigger('mousemove');

    })

    function factorial( value ){
        if ( typeof value !== 'number' ) return 0;

        value = Math.abs( Math.floor( value ) );

        for( var ans = 1; value > 0; value-- )
            ans *= value;

        return ans;
    }

    function pmf( n, k, p ){
        var p = p > 1 && 1 || p < 0 && 0 || p;
        return factorial(n)/factorial(k)/factorial(n-k) * Math.pow(p,k) * Math.pow( 1 - p, n - k );
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<h1 id="logo">
    <span class="w">w</span><span class="o">o</span><span class="r">r</span><span class="d">d</span><span class="space">&nbsp;</span><span class="a1">a</span><span class="r1">r</span><span class="r2">r</span><span class="a2">a</span><span class="n1">n</span><span class="g">g</span><span class="e1">e</span><span class="m">m</span><span class="e2">e</span><span class="n2">n</span><span class="t">t</span>
</h1>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

hi i have tried please check if it full fills your requirement
      [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mxJ22/)

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

    <style>
    h1#logo {
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: justify;
        font-size:1.8em;
        display:block;
        width:100%;
    }

    h1#logo:after {
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .word .w { }
    .word .o { padding-left:30px; }
    .word .r { padding-left:10px; }
    .word .d { padding-left:50px; }

    .arrangement .a1 { }
    .arrangement .r1 { }
    .arrangement .r2 { }
    .arrangement .a2 { }
    .arrangement .n1 { }
    .arrangement .g { }
    .arrangement .e1 { }
    .arrangement .m { }
    .arrangement .e2 { }
    .arrangement .n2 { }
    .arrangement .t { }
    </style>
    </head>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var count=0;
        //$(window).on("mousemove",function(e){




          var options = {};
        var oldx = 0;
        var direction = "";
        var stop_timeout = false;
        var stop_check_time = 150;
        $.mousedirection = function (opts) {
            var defaults = {};
            options = $.extend(defaults, opts);
            $(document).bind("mousemove", function (e) {
                var activeElement = e.target || e.srcElement;
                if (e.pageX > oldx) {
                    direction = "right";
                } else if (e.pageX < oldx) {
                    direction = "left";
                }

                clearTimeout(stop_timeout);
                stop_timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                    direction = "stop";
                    $(activeElement).trigger(direction);
                    $(activeElement).trigger({
                        type: "mousedirection",
                        direction: direction
                    });
                }, stop_check_time);

                $(activeElement).trigger(direction);
                $(activeElement).trigger({
                    type: "mousedirection",
                    direction: direction
                });
                oldx = e.pageX;
            });
        }

        $(function () {
        $.mousedirection();
        $(window).bind("mousedirection", function (e) {

            if(e.direction=="left")
            {
                count++;
                $(".word").filter(":first-child").css("margin-left",count+"px");
            }
            else if(e.direction=="right")
            {
                count--;
                $(".word").filter(":first-child").css("margin-left",count+"px");
            }

        });
    });








    });
    </script>
    <body>

     <header>
    <h1 id="logo">
        <span class="word">
            <span class="w">w</span>
            <span class="o">o</span>
            <span class="r">r</span>
            <span class="d">d</span>
        </span>
        <span class="arrangement">
            <span class="a1">a</span>
            <span class="r1">r</span>
            <span class="r2">r</span>
            <span class="a2">a</span>
            <span class="n1">n</span>
            <span class="g">g</span>
            <span class="e1">e</span>
            <span class="m">m</span>
            <span class="e2">e</span>
            <span class="n2">n</span>
            <span class="t">t</span>
        </span>
    </h1>
    </header>




      <script>

      </script>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: better you show this in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), so that anyone can easily validate.

Comment: It should always be visible with the same bounds left and right and within one line.